# Why does my project need google-services.json

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a project which uses a Google Map object inside it. I generated the key and the project runs well.
When I attempt to transfer the project to a new laptop, I generate a new debug key based on that laptop but when I run the project it requires the **google-services.json** file to be generated. Why is it asking for the file when on the other PC it does not ask for the file?

Comment: google-services.json file is always required when you're working with google play services library, so the solution is to get the file from google console and paste it in your project.

Comment: The comment from @Apurva is right, but I was curious about the project running in another computer. Are you sure that you don´t have the file? It was not in gitignore or something like that? Did you upgrade the google play services library version?

Comment: I actually copied the project folder on a thumb drive and transferred it2the other PC. I cant seem2also find the button to generate google-services.json @Apurva